# Adding an action field to a post using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm needing to add a some JSON to my serialized model using Django Rest Framework. It's purpose is simply to communicate to the api I am hitting what action to take. The json needs to be `action:"createproject"`

Below is an example of my serializer.

```
from models import Project
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes the Project model to send and receive valid JSON data.
    """
    action = serializers.SOMETYPEOFFIELDIMGUESSING(data="createproject")


    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ('action', 'title', 'id', 'endDate', 'startDate', 'product')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [`SerializerMethodField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to always add a `action` key having value as `createproject` to the serialized representation of your object.

From the DRF docs on `SerializerMethodField()`:

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on
>   the serializer class it is attached to. **It can be used to add any sort
>   of data to the serialized representation of your object**.

Your final code would be something like:

```
from models import Project
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes the Project model to send and receive valid JSON data.
    """
    # define a SerializerMethodField
    action = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name="get_data_for_action")    

    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ('action', 'title', 'id', 'endDate', 'startDate', 'product')


    def get_data_for_action(self, obj):
        return "createproject" # always add this value in the 'action' key of serialized object representation
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks very much for the help. I had tried something similar, but it didn't quite work. It seems I wasn't using the methodfield correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to use a `CharField` which would serialize and deserialize strings.

```
from models import Project
from rest_framework import serializers
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes the Project model to send and receive valid JSON data.
    """
    action = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ('action', 'title', 'id', 'endDate', 'startDate', 'product')
```

Then on your post you would either send `{"action": "createproject"}` as apart of your data. If you are trying to do it in your response then you would need to customize your view.